# iPhone Game Dev : Achievement Framework?

Tags: iphone, frameworks, game-center, achievements

I have written a simple game and am looking to integrate GameCenter Achievements with it.

I would like to try to do this in a clean and neat way which is easy to add extra achievements to.

As I see it an achievement has the following things:

- A Trigger 'group' (eg, on game end, on collision, etc)
- A Dependency (eg, you cannot get the "10 gold stars" until you have gained the "5 gold stars").

Based on this I tried to write a singleton class which read in a complete list (from a plist) of achievements, each one grouped by trigger class and with its dependencies. This singleton allowed other classes to register `@selector()`-like callbacks to trigger groups (eg, "on 'game_end' trigger, call this function"). These triggers could then be invoked cleanly at bespoke points in my game. This produced a neat, almost "abstract" system which I could use in future games.

Then disaster; I end up with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` errors which I can only assume is because I'm binding `@selector` callbacks from a non-static class into a static singleton class. The error appears on this line:

```
GCAchievementsHelper *h = [GCAchievementsHelper sharedInstance];
[h addEventListener:@"game_end" target:self selector:@selector(achievementHandlerGameEnd:)];
```

I'm assuming this is because "self" (the game layer) can't be passed into the static singleton?!

I really don't want to have to scatter tonnes of repeated IF statements around my code to check all the conditions I need for achievements... If at all possible!

To summarise, my question is:

> Does anybody know of an Achievement Framework? It doesn't have to be GC/OpenFeint or even ObjC compatible - even pseudo code would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of GameCenter Open Source frameworks that can leverage some load from you.

[GameCenterManager](https://github.com/sgonzalez/GameCenterManager) Which follows the singleton pattern and is quite "light"

[iOS Game Center Cache](https://github.com/anton-nikan/iOS-Game-Center-Cache) is a full featured Game Center framework.

I would suggest you to look at both of them...

Good luck :)

Comment: Both of those look fantastic - thanks for the links. Although both look like they require the game to tell them that an achievement has been "had". I still need to find a way of defining achievements (both in terms of trigger and dependencies/requirements) in an abstract kind of way.

Comment: Well for that you could use SQLite, this guy suggest ( http://www.reedolsen.com/how-to-develop-achievements-for-iphone-games/ ) something that you could imitate. Basically, you just track statistics with SQLite, and you could then create a trigger to check for achievements earned.